# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (caused by .value statement)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm facing a slight problem when testing how to retreive user's input into a function to be used later on.

Specifically, in the line: *decimalNum = document.getElementById("decimalNum").**value**;*
there is the problem with the 'value' method - it says that the element's value is null. It says so, even if I run the code and input a number.

What am I doing wrong? How do I get to use the user's input in a function?

**Problem resolved, I will accept the asnwer as sooon as I can (cooldown).**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Converter from Decimal to Binary</h1>
    <label for ="decimalNum"> Decimal (natural number): </label>
    <input type = "number"> 
    <button id="mySubmit"> Submit </button>
    <p id="binaryNum">  </p> <!-- Placeholder for the printed form in the Binary system.-->
    <button id="testing"> Test</button>
    <script>
        let decimalNum;

        document.getElementById("mySubmit").onclick = function() {;
            decimalNum = document.getElementById("decimalNum").value;
            document.getElementById("binaryNum").textContent = `Here is your number in the Binary system: ${decimalNum}`;
        };

        document.getElementById("testing").onclick = console.log('test was a success')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any element in your HTML that has `id="decimalNum"`?

Comment: _"it says that the element's value is null"_ - Not exactly, it's saying that the element you're trying to retrieve using `getElementById()` is `null` (so the thing you're using `.value` on is `null`).

Comment: @Ivar My apologies, I'm new to working with JS. I accidentally used 'number' id. It works now. Thank you for the help, I've been stuck for half an hour on this redundancy.

Comment: Please don't edit the title with *answered*. If someone posted an answer that was helpful then please upvote and/or accept the specific anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input element is missing the *id* attribute, which is needed to correctly identify the element.

You can try the following way:

```html
<body>
<h1>Converter from Decimal to Binary</h1>
<label for="decimalNum">Decimal (natural number): </label>
<input type="number" id="decimalNum"> <!-- Added id attribute -->
<button id="mySubmit">Submit</button>
<p id="binaryNum"></p> <!-- Placeholder for the printed form in the Binary system.-->
<button id="testing">Test</button>
<script>
    let decimalNum;

    document.getElementById("mySubmit").onclick = function() {
      decimalNum = document.getElementById("decimalNum").value;
      document.getElementById("binaryNum").textContent = `Here is your number in the Binary system: ${decimalNum}`;
    };

    document.getElementById("testing").onclick = function() {
      console.log('test was a success');
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `id="decimalNum"` to your input:
`<input type="number" id="decimalNum">`

Answer (score 0):

Two changes in your code is required.

Like other answers says:

Add ID to the input field.

```
<input type="number" id="decimalNum">
```

Second is the prevent the event like below:

```
document.getElementById("mySubmit").onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior
    decimalNum = document.getElementById("decimalNum").value;
    document.getElementById("binaryNum").textContent = `Here is your number in the Binary system: ${decimalNum}`;
};
```